# How can I build a predicate filtering to where ALL tags in an array exist, joined to a record, using criteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Here's an example of the syntax I'm using for another condition (where ANY of the tags appear on the document via a FK).

`predicates.add(root.join(Document_.tags).in({ pseudocode array of tags }));`

I'm trying to come up with a similar predicate, but where the Document entity has ALL of the tags listed in the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all the tags listed in the filters are all the tags that exist you could try this

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.size(root.get(Document_.tags)),
    countOfAllTheTags));
```

or, if the tags in the filter are a subset of all of the tags, try this one

```
predicates.addAll(Stream.of(tags)
    .map(tag -> criteriaBuilder.isMember(tag, root.get(Document_.tags)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The latter was what I was going for. Worked like a charm with very slight tweaks just relating to the actual types I was working with.

`predicates.addAll(tags.stream().map(t -> criteriaBuilder.isMember(t, root.get(Document_.tags))).collect(Collectors.toList()));`